I can't see data from my related entities in a smart table odata v2
I want to show data of my entity agreements in a smart table, including its business partner (business_partner_per_agreement), but it comes up empty.

As you can see below, it is a one-to-many relationship but it seems that the table does not have the ability to display data in these relationships.
I was able to get the data to be seen with a custom column but when filtering or using the table customization everything is damaged, I would like to find a way to maintain the relationship but have the view manage this data just as it is done in Fiori Elements, which is visible.
Metadata:
<EntityType Name="Agreements">
    <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="ID"/>
        <PropertyRef Name="VALID_FROM"/>
    </Key>
    <Property Name="ID" Type="Edm.Guid" Nullable="false"/>
    <Property Name="CREATED_AT" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Precision="7"/>
    <Property Name="CREATED_BY" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="255"/>
    <Property Name="MODIFIED_AT" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Precision="7"/>
    <Property Name="MODIFIED_BY" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="255"/>
    <Property Name="DELETED" Type="Edm.Boolean"/>
    <Property Name="DELETED_AT" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Precision="7"/>
    <Property Name="DELETED_BY" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="255"/>
    <Property Name="VALID_FROM" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Precision="7" Nullable="false"/>
    <Property Name="VALID_TO" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Precision="7"/>
    <Property Name="DESCRIPTION" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="250"/>
    <Property Name="CURRENCY" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="3"/>
    <Property Name="EXTERNAL_CONTRACT_IDENTIFIER" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="15"/>
    <Property Name="STATUS" Type="Edm.Boolean"/>
    <Property Name="DEACTIVATED_AT" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Precision="7"/>
    <Property Name="TYPE_CODE" Type="Edm.Int32"/>
    <Property Name="PRIORITY_CODE" Type="Edm.Int32"/>
    <NavigationProperty Name="BUSINESS_PARTNERS_PER_AGREEMENT" Relationship="Agreement.Agreements_BUSINESS_PARTNERS_PER_AGREEMENT" FromRole="Agreements" ToRole="Business_partners_per_agreement"/>
    <NavigationProperty Name="SITE_BUNDLES_HEADER" Relationship="Agreement.Agreements_SITE_BUNDLES_HEADER" FromRole="Agreements" ToRole="Site_bundles_headers"/>
    <NavigationProperty Name="ADDED_ELEMENT_TO_AGREMMENT" Relationship="Agreement.Agreements_ADDED_ELEMENT_TO_AGREMMENT" FromRole="Agreements" ToRole="Added_element_to_agremment"/>
    <NavigationProperty Name="SERVICES_PER_AGREEMENT" Relationship="Agreement.Agreements_SERVICES_PER_AGREEMENT" FromRole="Agreements" ToRole="services_per_agreement"/>
</EntityType>

<EntityType Name="Business_partners_per_agreement">
    <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="ID"/>
    </Key>
    <Property Name="ID" Type="Edm.Guid" Nullable="false"/>
    <Property Name="CREATED_AT" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Precision="7"/>
    <Property Name="CREATED_BY" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="255"/>
    <Property Name="MODIFIED_AT" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Precision="7"/>
    <Property Name="MODIFIED_BY" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="255"/>
    <Property Name="DELETED" Type="Edm.Boolean"/>
    <Property Name="DELETED_AT" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Precision="7"/>
    <Property Name="DELETED_BY" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="255"/>
    <Property Name="VALID_FROM" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Precision="7"/>
    <Property Name="VALID_TO" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Precision="7"/>
    <Property Name="BUSINESS_PARTNER" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="10"/>
    <Property Name="BUSINESS_PARTNER_NAME" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="255"/>
    <Property Name="AGREEMENT_ID" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="36"/>
    <NavigationProperty Name="AGREEMENT" Relationship="Agreement.Business_partners_per_agreement_AGREEMENT" FromRole="Business_partners_per_agreement" ToRole="Agreements"/>
</EntityType>


<Annotation Term="UI.LineItem">
    <Collection>
    <Record Type="UI.DataField">
        <PropertyValue Property="Value" Path="BUSINESS_PARTNERS_PER_AGREEMENT/BUSINESS_PARTNER_NAME" />
    </Record> 
        <Record Type="UI.DataField">
            <PropertyValue Property="Value" Path="ID" />
            <PropertyValue Property="Label" String="{@i18n>id}" />
            <Annotation Term="HTML5.CssDefaults">
                <Record Type="HTML5.CssDefaultsType">
                    <PropertyValue Property="width" String="14.28%" />
                </Record>
            </Annotation>
        </Record>
        <Record Type="UI.DataField">
            <PropertyValue Property="Value" Path="VALID_FROM" />
            <PropertyValue Property="Label" String="{@i18n>startDate}" />
            <Annotation Term="HTML5.CssDefaults">
                <Record Type="HTML5.CssDefaultsType">
                    <PropertyValue Property="width" String="14.28%" />
                </Record>
            </Annotation>
        </Record>
        <Record Type="UI.DataField">
            <PropertyValue Property="Value" Path="VALID_TO" />
            <PropertyValue Property="Label" String="{@i18n>endDate}" />
            <Annotation Term="HTML5.CssDefaults">
                <Record Type="HTML5.CssDefaultsType">
                    <PropertyValue Property="width" String="14.28%" />
                </Record>
            </Annotation>
        </Record>
        <Record Type="UI.DataField">
            <PropertyValue Property="Value" Path="EXTERNAL_CONTRACT_IDENTIFIER" />
            <PropertyValue Property="Label" String="{@i18n>externalContractIdentifier}" />
            <Annotation Term="HTML5.CssDefaults">
                <Record Type="HTML5.CssDefaultsType">
                    <PropertyValue Property="width" String="14.28%" />
                </Record>
            </Annotation>
        </Record>
    </Collection>
</Annotation>

<Annotation Term="UI.SelectionFields">
    <Collection>
        <PropertyPath>BUSINESS_PARTNERS_PER_AGREEMENT/VALID_FROM</PropertyPath>
        <PropertyPath>VALID_FROM</PropertyPath>
        <PropertyPath>VALID_TO</PropertyPath>
        <PropertyPath>STATUS</PropertyPath>
    </Collection>
</Annotation>

